# AngularJS ensure checkbox value isset in a initial loaded form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've created one form there are multiple checkbox at edit time that form checkbox is coming with checked using below code.

#### View

```
<form method="POST" name="LeadCircle" role="form" ng-submit="addLeadCircle()">
  <input type="hidden" ng-model="form.addleadcircle.leadId" name="leadId" />
  <div class="select-basket">
    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="circle in circles">
      <input class="checkboxCircle" type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{circle.checked}}" name="leadcircle[]" ng-model="form.addleadcircle.leadcircle[circle.Id]" value="{{circle.Id}}" id="cb-{{circle.Id}}">
      <label for="cb-{{circle.Id}}">{{circle.Name}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary button-sm text-uppercase pull-right">Add</button>
</form>
```

#### AnguarJS

```
$scope.addLeadCircle = function () {
     console.log($scope.form.addleadcircle);
     return false; 
     dataFactory.httpRequest(base_url + 'leadCircles/addLeadCircle', 'POST', {}, $scope.form.addleadcircle).then(function (data) {
         alertify.notify('Assign circle successfully', 'success', 5, function () {});
         return;
     });
}
```

This code also shows checked checkbox which value need to check. but what happen if I'm try to submit form it will not gives value of this already checked checkbox If I'm going to select new checkbox it will gives value of that newly checked checkbox.

Now in console at edit form If I will submit form directly without checked any checkbox so It will take only hidden input value not already selected checkbox value. If I am select new checkbox then it takes only newly selected checkbox value.

Any one can please help on this Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your form / submit action / controller? Please add a full example of what you got. Thanks.

Comment: I have added whole form code. can you please help now.

Comment: Could you please add the controller & circles data? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your code. First, `ng-checked` expects an object and not an string. You should change it to `ng-checked="circle.checked"`. You also need no `value` attribute because `ng-model` holds you input value. Instead of using `ng-checked` I would prefer to use `ng-init` to create a default value on your `ng-model`. In that way you will always have a param set for each checkbox on submit. It also makes `ng-checked` obsolete because `ng-model` handles the "check" status.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="submit()">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
      <input class="checkboxCircle" 
      type="checkbox" 
      name="leadcircle[]" 
      ng-model="form.addleadcircle.leadcircle[item.id]" 
      ng-init="form.addleadcircle.leadcircle[item.id] = item.value" // <- ensure init value
      id="cb-{{item.id}}"> {{item.id}}
    </div>
    <button type="submit">
      Send
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.form = {
    addleadcircle: {
      leadcircle: []
    }
  }

  $scope.data = [{
    id: 1,
    value: true
  }, {
    id: 2,
    value: false
  }, {
    id: 3,
    value: false
  }, {
    id: 4,
    value: true
  }, {
    id: 5,
    value: false
  }, {
    id: 6,
    value: true
  }, {
    id: 7,
    value: true
  }, {
    id: 8,
    value: false
  }];

  $scope.submit = function () {
    console.log($scope.form);
  }
});
```

**>> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3jxn0x2/)**

Comment: @in Thanks it works. Actually I tried ng-init but don't know at that time it not works. Thanks for you help.  Accepted  + 1

Comment: @in Can you please suggest me how to use select 2 in angular js I checked some where says use ui-select some where suggest used simple select 2 which is better.

Comment: @DenisBhojvani please create a new question and post your code. Also link your new question here. I will help you inside your new question.

Comment: @In this question regarding full calendar can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458527/how-to-update-event-source-object-to-particular-event-source-in-full-calendar-dy